# How to query on Salesforce object query language from Salesforce through Sitecore data exchange framework?

Tags: data-exchange-framework

Hi I am `Sitecore Data Exchange framework 3.0.0 and Sitecore 9.2`.

I want to query over Salesforce object to select distinct data based on some conditions. And create sitecore item with it.

How to achieve that?
Any help is appreciated.